# Extrema of $f(x)=\frac{\sin (5x)} 5 - \frac{2\sin(3x)} {3} + \sin (x)$.

Tags: calculus, optimization

(a) I need help in finding maxima and minima of the following funcion:

$$f(x)=\frac{\sin (5x)} 5 - \frac{2\sin(3x)} {3} + \sin (x)$$

therefore I need to find the roots of $f'(x)=\cos(5x)-2\cos(3x)+\cos(x)$.

(b) I need to find the minima of $$f(x)=4x+\frac{9\pi^2} x + \sin x.$$
How can I find the roots of $$f'(x)=4-\frac{9\pi^2 }{x^2} + \cos x?$$

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

a) $\cos(5x) \equiv 16\cos^5(x)-20\cos^3(x)+5\cos(x)$

$\cos(3x) \equiv 4\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)$

So, we've got:

Now, let $c \equiv \cos(x)$.

We've got:

$$[16c^5-10c^3+5c]-2[4c^3-3c]+c=0 \iff \boxed{2c\underbrace{[8c^4-9c^2+6=0]}_{\textrm{quadratic in} \ c^2}} \tag{A}$$

Solve $(A)$!

b) Solving this analytically is very hard, so use the bisection method (noting that $4-\frac{9\pi^2}{x^2}=\cos(x)=0$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R \setminus\{0\}}$).

The exact answer to b) is $\boxed{\pm \frac{3\pi}{2}}$.

Now, your job is to evaluate the second derivative of these extrema, in order to determine their nature (maxima or minima).

Comment: How does the bisection method work?

Comment: Essentially, it boils down to guessing.

e.g. for a simple equation, let's say we want a solution to $$x^2-4.76x+4.41=0$$.

Now, let's guess $x=0$. Plugging this in, we get $4.41>0$.

Now let's guess $x=2$. Plugging this in, we get $-1.11<0$. So the graph changes sign between $x=0$ and $x=2$, so (since the function is continuous) there must be a root inbetween $x=0$ and $x=2$.

We then test the midpoint of $0$ and $2$ (1) , and sub that into the equation. We keep on doing this until we have a more-accurate value of the root.

Comment: so after guessing the root you need to prove that the function is monotone? Otherwise, if you can find more roots you could wish that the function is convex or concave between two subsequent roots to prove that there are no more roots (although the converse it's obviously  false)?

Comment: I doesn't have to even be monotone; it could go up and down millions of times between the two guesses (all that the bisection method tells us is that there is *at least* one root between these two points- there could be millions of roots). What is essential, though, is that the function be *continuous*.

See the Intermediate Value Theorem- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem

Comment: yes, what I meant is that if you want to prove that you found all roots, that could be an argument (among many others).

Comment: No- unfortunately, with the bisection method, you can't guarantee that you've found all roots; only that certain roots exist.

Comment: the only thing I was saying was that if you found a root and the function is monotone, then that's the only root.

if you found more than one root and the function is either convex or concave between each pair of subsequent roots (possibly changing convexity between pairs) then those are the only roots

Comment: Ah, yes! Sorry; I misinterpreted that. Yep- if a function's strictly monotone between two points, and if there's a change of sign, then there's one and only one point (in this interval) at which the curve crosses the x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for (a): $\cos 5x+\cos x=2\cos 3x\cos 2x$

For (b), I think you will need a numerical method, such as Newton's Method.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\cos5x-2\cos3x+\cos x&=\cos5x-\cos 3x + \cos x-\cos 3x\\
&=-2\sin4x\sin x+2\sin2x\sin x\\
&=2\sin x(-\sin 4x+\sin2x)\\
&=-4\sin x\sin3x\cos x
\end{align}$$

Now you only have to equal $0$ to each factor.